# How to access a dynamic key in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I have the following code:

```
type StringMapType<K extends string[]> = Record<K[number], string>

const en = {
  'general': {
    'hi': {
      string: 'Aenean ullamcorper neque id elementum commodo. {{firstName}}',
      params: ['firstName']
    },
     'bye': {
      string: 'Aenean ullamcorper neque id elementum commodo.',
      params: null
    }
  },
} as const


const getLocalizedString = <ContextType extends keyof typeof en, KeyType extends keyof typeof en[ContextType], ParamsType extends typeof en[ContextType][KeyType]['params']>(context: ContextType, key: KeyType, ...params: typeof en[ContextType][KeyType]['params'] extends null ? [undefined?] : [StringMapType<ParamsType>]) => {
  // Code that would return the correct value
}


getLocalizedString('general', 'hi', {
  firstName: 'John'
})
```

For some reason, I'm getting an error on the `ParamsType` saying that `Type '"params"' cannot be used to index type`. The code itself works and does what I want, just wondering if there is any way how to get around this error.

[Demo](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAysBOBLAdgcwLIEMwBVwQB4BpKCAD2AmQBMBnKWhFVAbQF0A+KAXigCUIAYwD28asRbIArgFsARhHhsANAyZoOAKE0jkjUsh5QA3pqhQA5KiqLMAGwsAuE2fOWAFoicu3bxkjRnCwBBG0xDKTs7TBkReEh4KGQIAEcpaERqUjsIGSpgWSgRGRlhamEAOhNjADNEeEYAORiIAF9Wi2VXXzBMeBjaZxYLOobgZryLNm6oVq7fSzkQCG9TBbUA1CDQ5PCoSOjY0QSk1PSoTOzc-MLi0vKKzpnzXv6ZQaSDmdbXOc1WqCYei6RjaHTCPTAKDWYAAGWEgnsiAAXhBqHBNkYCABhCGUCh4SCkChUOhQADWEBAwhqUFAkBpBlURCphOg5EoNHolOptPpEEZVBYuOQ+OAbJUUAACn0BmziZyyfzBchhXiORKWCyQJqLK8BlMOAAKXRi5wisVs1Q85zaq1QCqO-XvZzK2lCi0a-BsLWs73DZ20KYK0n0aRRKAAfigLCkNAgdWS1EjbCgQwxzCwuHwBBlb1obI4bAAlDwuGsoAB6StQXHUaDAdyYKEAd2EkSy8AgBXghkb0DiXcEUIAbvZ0v8wTD4Yi7Ci0Rm0EarDZ+g5VBZPJ0fFBRk0WkEAFLCdzICz-YtAA)

Thanks in advance

## Solution

Based on @seti's answer

```
const en = {
  general: {
    hi: {
      string: 'hi, {{firstName}}',
      params: ['firstName'] as const,
    },
    bye: {
      string: 'bye',
      params: [] as const,
    }
  },
} as const

const translations = {
  en,
} as const

const language = 'en'

type CT = keyof typeof en
type KT = keyof typeof en[CT]
type ParamsType<KeyType extends KT> = typeof en[CT][KeyType]['params'][number]
type StringType<KeyType extends KT> = typeof en[CT][KeyType]['string']

const getLocalizedString = <ContextType extends CT = CT, KeyType extends KT = KT>(
  context: ContextType,
  key: KeyType,
  ...params: ParamsType<KeyType> extends undefined ? [undefined?] : [{ [key in ParamsType<KeyType>]: string }]
): StringType<KeyType> => {

  return translations[language][context][key].string
}

getLocalizedString('general', 'hi', {firstName: 'John'})

getLocalizedString('general', 'bye')
```

Comment: Why do you need to capture the valid keys at the type level?

Comment: I think this is a limitation of TypeScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have wrote [Example Solution](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAysBOBLAdgcwLIEMwBVwQB4BpKCAD2AmQBMBnKWhFVAbQF0A+KAXigCUIAYwD28agQDWEEMIBmUIi2QBXALYAjCPDZQAZAyZoANAaRoOAKAsjkjUsh5QA3hahQA5KipbMAG3cAXM6ubh4AFoiBwaGhjGaoQe4Agt6YDsq+vpiqIvCQ8FDIEACOytCI1KS+EKpUwGpQIqqqwtTCAHTOTrKI8IwActkQAL7D7kYhMWCY8Nm0QSzuPX3Ag7XjHpSM7jqY9DaMk1DDEzEe6iAQUS5npsyJKUVpUBlZOaL5hSVlUBVVNXUGk0Wm12uMjm5prNVPMoIsyDsoHtGsJbMAjsMQicLMMkftUYwANxWCygSBQAAajikMnkZIgcnsxPpUAAmtTpIz6YyqCwKWxmfgoAB1Rzc+S8-ksVlsRZxZg7QXkgBiBFZ7PIlBo9FZXF44vsfNl6tl7ihcx2SjUmm0SugAHE1RqKFQ6Ao1Rw9c4WDTfg5VeqOGwgvK0MM7e71aQXdq2V71cTrATgFAvMAADLCQR+RAALwg1Dg8UcxBImtdOscrJM9vtjgEpV6BYITh90j9UFVRCIQZDhlQww4JgpVPLsapvApHAAFDZKBQgiOTDSgt2TO0N+aYUFa+wAJQ8LguHEkixpzPZ3x5gtF5jTzzeWb+EzuCIbG5QZYDIaJABSwjCZBwTcTBQMSTBwWGPdE3PLMc3zQt+3vLwiifDZ3AuK4TBudwQCidxIOgoA) for you, and have split the declarations into several parts

So this monstrocity:

```
type StringMapType<K extends string[]> = Record<keyof K[number] & string, string>

const en = {
  'general': {
    'hi': {
      string: 'Aenean ullamcorper neque id elementum commodo. {{firstName}}',
      params: ['firstName', 'test'] as const
    },
     'bye': {
      string: 'Aenean ullamcorper neque id elementum commodo.',
      params: ['x'] as const
    }
  },
} as const;


type X = keyof typeof en;
type Y = keyof typeof en[X];
type W = typeof en[X][Y]['string'];
type F<YY extends Y> = typeof en[X][YY]['params'][number];
type G<YY extends K<Y>> = {[key in F<YY>]: string};
type K<YY extends Y> = YY;


const getLocalizedString = <KK extends Y = Y, GG = Required<{[key in F<KK>]: string}>, XX extends X = X>(context: XX, key: KK, ...params: GG[]) => {

}



getLocalizedString('general', 'hi', {
  firstName: 'John',
  aaa: 'a',
});

getLocalizedString('general', 'bye', {
 'y': '',
});
```

From that you can experiment more.
Only one issue with this - it do not check against wrong, but you have some starting point now

Comment: Thanks a ton! This was pretty much all I needed, did a couple of modifications to check for errors and got it working great!

Comment: Can you share yours code so we all could see it in the end?^^

Comment: edited the question with a solution :)